# Is there a simple way to print out the 1's and 0's from an mpg file?

Tags: python, r, binary, mpeg

Working on a art project and would like the "row vector of 1's and 0's" associated with an increment of sound to print to screen sequentially.  Am I asking the question poorly?  If so any ideas for what the correct problem statement would be?  As for languages, I'm think python or R.  But if there is another language that someone could suggest I'm somewhat open.

Example:

```
 $ 1.) 1010100000001111111010101110011101110101   (sound at time = 0)
 $ 2.) 1111100010101011010101011010110100010100   (sound at time = 1)
 $ 3.) 1110001010101010111110000010101011010111   (sound at time = 2)
 ....
```

Comment: this link may help get you started http://www.johnny-lin.com/cdat_tips/tips_fileio/bin_array.html, maybe not, i am new to python

Comment: You will want to decode the mpg file first, otherwise it will look like just a bunch of noise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know exactly what you mean but you don't necessarily need to write any code to get a binary dump of a file.  For instance, on linux you can do

`xxd -b filename`

to get a binary dump.

Comment: Wow thank you! The rest I can just do in awk. Had no idea it would be so simple!